# How to create a Dropdown in Powerpoint using Combolist that links to Slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I was trying to create a VBA Combolist Dropdown in Powerpoint and name the list as

```
Car
bike
boat
```

I would like to display All the 3 names after clicking on the dropdown and after selecting car it should take to slide 1, and bike to slide 2, and finally boat to slide 3.

I am using `ComboBox1_change()` instead of `Load()`:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    On Error Resume Next
    SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide ComboBox1
    ComboBox1.Value = "car"
    ComboBox1.Value = "bike"
    ComboBox1.Value = "boat
    ComboBox1.ListRows = 3
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_GotFocus()
    Dim s As Long
    With ComboBox1
        .Clear
        For s = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
            .AddItem s
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

End Sub
```

Can Someone help me with it

Comment: I think you're probably using `vba`, not `vb6` in Powerpoint?  Using the correct tags will get better answers.

Comment: You haven't explained what your actual question is - what is the problem with what happens now?

Comment: Remove the "On error resume next" line ... it's only masking whatever's going wrong.